# How to delete specific files from timthumb's cache?

Tags: php, timthumb

I have a photo sharing app and I use [timthumb](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) to display the thumbnails. When a user delete a photo, I want the cached images also deleted from the timthumb's cache directory to save space. Currently I can only delete all files from cache, but it is less than ideal.

How to delete only specific files from timthumb's cache given the original image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to this solution. I have to make little modifications to the `timthumb.php`
file so I can include the file and instantiate the class from another file.

**timthumb.php:**

```
<?php

// If this file is included from other script, don't start timthumb
if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == basename(__FILE__)) {
  timthumb::start();
}

class timthumb {
  ...
  // $cachefile is protected so I create a getter function
  public function getCacheFile() {
    return $this->cachefile;
  }
}
```

Now I can get the cache filename for a given image and delete it. The code is not pretty, but I need to save space.

**delete_cache.php:**

```
<?php
require 'timthumb.php';

// Fake the query string
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = 'src=path/to/src/image.jpg&w=200&h=150';
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);

// When instantiated, timthumb will generate some properties: 
// salt, directories, cachefile, etc.
$t = new timthumb();

// Get the cache file name
$f = $t->getCacheFile();

// Delete the file
if (file_exists($f)) {
    unlink($f);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

asuming we want to delete the cache file of a local image:

first thing we need is the cacheDirectory = **'./cache'**
second, the FILE_CACHE_PREFIX = **'timthumb'**
then that it is internal **(_int_)**
then there is an **md5** hash of:

- timthumb.php's modification time
- char '-'
- timthumb.php's inode
- image's modification time
- the $_SERVER ['QUERY_STRING'] when you call the image
- the *'fileCacheVersion'* which is always the nubmer 1

and lastly, the FILE_CACHE_SUFFIX = **'.timthumb.txt'**

for example:

HTML:

```
<img src='timthumb.php?src=images/example.png&w=150'>
```

PHP:

```
$cachefile = 'cache/timthumb_int_'.md5(filemtime('timthumb.php') . '-' . fileinode('timthumb.php') . filemtime("images/example.png"). "src=images/example.png&w=150" . 1) . '.timthumb.txt';
unlink($cachefile);
```